# add new div dynamically but click event is not working on new divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a button so that when I click on it it creates a new button after it then when I click on the next/new button it will create a button after itself  but the click event only works on the first button, can you help?

Here is my fiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/hyeFB/

```
// $(document).ready(function () {


    var myDiv = '<div class="myButton">myButton</div>';


     $('#c').append(myDiv);


     $('.myButton').click(function () {

         $(this).after(myDiv);

     });


 //});​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `on`

```
var myDiv = '<div class="myButton">myButton</div>';

 $('#c').append(myDiv);

 $('body').on('click', '.myButton',function () {
     $(this).after(myDiv);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// $(document).ready(function () {


    var myDiv = '<div class="myButton">myButton</div>';


     $('#c').append(myDiv);


     $('.myButton').live(function () {

         $(this).after(myDiv);

     });

   // Or Use delegation
  $('body').delegate('.myButton','click',function () {

         $(this).after(myDiv);

     });


 //});
```

Would do the trick. http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more info.

Note that `live` is deprecated starting with jquery 1.7, so the above answer is the more correct one for 1.7+

Comment: `live` is depreciated use `delegate` or `on`

Comment: I know. Since no jQuery version was given, I felt the need to show another option.